# Ошибка при динамическом включении jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

```
public class main extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String page ="common/home";
        req.setAttribute("page",page);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("view/index.jsp").forward(req,resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Файл JSP

```
 <body>
  <%@include file="common/header.jsp" %>
  <div id="bod">

      <%
              String p = request.getAttribute("page").toString();
              out.print(p+".jsp");

      %>
      <jsp:include page="<%= p+".jsp"%>"/>

  </div>

  <%@include file="common/footer.jsp" %>
  </body>
```

При запуске получаю ошибку 500

> Exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.view.index_jsp
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:604)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:422)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>     catalog.view.common.main.doGet(main.java:17)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Comment: <jsp:include page="<%= p+".jsp"%>"/> и строка <jsp:include page="common/home.jsp"/> ведь соответствует а при последнем ошибки нет

Comment: Решил проблему включением    <jsp:include page="${page}"></jsp:include>